# Windows 10 - disable reopening programs after power loss

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios

After my computer turns back on after a power outage, all the programs that were running restart.  How can I prevent that?

I know about the [sign-in option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHjOq.jpg) which fixes this if the computer is turned off manually but **not** if it's turned off because of power outage.

Comment: You would have to disable hybrid startup in order to prevent Windows from restoring your session after a sudden loss of power.  (Windows uses the file that is created to restore your applications).